# Finding an email address in a text file

Tags: java

I am working on a web project and it will be used for a login page.  I have a file named database.txt where the user's information (name, email, password) is stored. I do not have the login page yet, but I have created a method and tried to test it, but I'm not getting any results as output to see if it works.

Here is my current code:

```
public static User select(String emailAddress)     
{
    emailAddress = "randomuser@yahoo.com";//testing with an email that is in  the database.txt file.   
    User userID = null;
    String file="/Users/test/Downloads/MyTwitter/web/database.txt";
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);
    while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
        final String lineFromFile = scanner.nextLine();
        if (lineFromFile.contains(emailAddress)) { 
            System.out.println("I found" + emailAddress);
            userID = new User();
            break;              
        }

    }
    return userID;    
}
```

Comment: Do you have a specific question?

Comment: I do not mean to be disparaging but whatever happen to this site being for professionals?

Comment: There's no barrier for entry to this site... so anybody can sign up and post questions.

Comment: Just calling your variable `file` doesn't actually *make* it one.  You're not parsing the contents of `/Users/test/Downloads/MyTwitter/web/database.txt`, you are parsing the **string** `"/Users/test/Downloads/MyTwitter/web/database.txt"`.

Answer (score 0):

You're invoking the wrong Scanner constructor, you are pasing the String value. Try this:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("/Users/test/Downloads/MyTwitter/web/database.txt"));
```